# Does the sticker counter include duplicate stickers?

Tags: kirby-planet-robobot

At the top of the sticker room screen, there's a counter next to a yellow star that shows how many stickers you've collected. Does this counter include duplicate stickers, or does it only count unique stickers?

[image: sticker room counter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the sticker counter does not count duplicates. Only unique stickers are counted. Tested by spending play coins on stickers until I got a duplicate.